# How to multiply two columns and display that in another column in a gridview using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Here is the gridview part. Somebody please help me to find the answer. I want to multiply `Count` and `Price` and display the sum in `Amount`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCardPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count")%>'></asp:Label>                                        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("(Amount)")%>'></asp:Label>                                        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i posted answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" >
<ItemTemplate >

<asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#  Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Count"))*Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Price"))%>'></asp:Label>                                        
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```